# Linq To Sql select command

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Can you help me change this select command to linq to sql select command?

```
string value = ddl.SelectedValue;

SELECT  * 
FROM    Song 
WHERE   SongID IN (
            SELECT SongID 
            FROM   AlbumSong 
            WHERE  AlbumID = @value)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you created the DBML yet?  Can you post what your first attempt looks like, so we can take it from there?

Comment: Questions of the form: "Please do this for me" imply you should either post what you have tried or go try some things so you can post what you tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the linq approach with the more concise `dot notation`

```
var dataContext = new YouDataContext();
int value = 10;
dataContext.Song.Where(a => 
     dataContext.AlbumSong.Where(alSong => alSong.AlbumId == value)
                          .Select(alSong => alSong.SongId).Contains(a.SongId));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

`"SELECT * FROM Song WHERE SongID in (SELECT SongID FROM AlbumSong WHERE AlbumID = " + value + ")"`

Is there a reason why you're not using a join here, instead of the nested select?  Like:

`"SELECT * FROM Song INNER JOIN AlbumSong ON Song.SongId = AlbumSong.SongId WHERE AlbumID = " + value`

Or have I misunderstood your needs here and a join isn't appropriate?

Comment: Yes, it can instead of that select. 
However, I need a linqtosql command